# SharePoint Learning Kit (SLK) Do I need to activate all 3 Features?

Tags: sharepoint, slk

I'm having fun deploying some solutions to my SharePoint 2013 Foundation Edition. I'm checking out some eLearning Solutions, currently the SharePoint Learning Kit (SLK).

The solution comes with 3 Features:

- SLK
- SLK - Assign Self
- SLK - Assign to Site

I guess I need the "SLK" Feature to activate the Solution but if I activate the other two features, I dont see any differences.

Can somebody tell me if I need to activate those two, that the solution works and what they are there for?

Thanks in Advance

-DaveTheMave

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To simply answer your question - No, you don't need those 2 additional features, the SLK will work perfectly without them.
I don't have them activated myself.

Here is what the do:

**Assign Self:** 
This feature add the "Assign To Self" menu item to document libraries. This allows the user to immediately assign an item to themselves and run it.

**Assign to Site:**
This feature add the "Assign To Site" menu item to document libraries. This allows the user to start assigning an item to the current site without having to choose the site to assign to. In effect it jumps straight to the Assignment Properties page for the current site.

As you are new to the SLK, I can highly recommend you [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jG07se2R_pg) YouTube Tutorial on "how to get started with SLK".

Comment: Is it possible that not all SLK functionalities work on the Foundation Version of SharePoint 2013?

Comment: @DaveTheMave I tested the SLK first on my Foundation Server before I deployed it to our Enterprise - had no problems there. What doesnt work in your opinion?

Comment: In the tutorial you linked me there is the Assignment List Web Part, but I dont have have this Web Part in my Collection to choose. 
I redeployed the solution and activated all features again but it still doesnt show up